# Python script that connects to the Reddit api is not returning expected results

Tags: python-3.x, reddit

I just started learning about the Reddit api and I used a praw tutorial to make the following python script.

I want the script to pull the top 500 threads in the /r/cars subreddit.

I got it to run, but it takes like 15-20 seconds to run, but then only spits out 1 thread...not 500 like I am hoping for.

Here is my script.  What would cause it to take a long time then only return one thread?

Thanks!

```
import praw
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id="xxxx", client_secret="xxxx",
                     password="!!!!", user_agent="redditApp",
                     username="!!!!")
                     
subreddit = reddit.subreddit('cars')

top_subreddit = subreddit.top()

top_subreddit = subreddit.top(limit=500)

for submission in subreddit.top(limit=1):
    print(submission.title, submission.id)
    
    
topics_dict = { "title":[], 
            "score":[], 
            "id":[], 
            "url":[], 
            "comms_num": [], 
            "created": [], 
            "body":[]
        }
            
for submission in top_subreddit:
    topics_dict["title"].append(submission.title)
    topics_dict["score"].append(submission.score)
    topics_dict["id"].append(submission.id)
    topics_dict["url"].append(submission.url)
    topics_dict["comms_num"].append(submission.num_comments)
    topics_dict["created"].append(submission.created)
    topics_dict["body"].append(submission.selftext)
    
topics_data = pd.DataFrame(topics_dict)
```

Comment: Do you ever print your dataframe after this? It looks you just print one submission title and id and then make a dataframe with 500 entries.

Comment: @T Im sorry Im new to Python.  What do you mean data frame?

Comment: In you last line, you create `topics_data` which is a Pandas data frame. This is basically just a spreadsheet that you can move around/modify programmatically. It looks like you load all the values you want into this variable, but then you never actually print them out.